# Where is instance method "each_with_index" defined?

Tags: ruby, enumerable

I am looking in [Ruby 1.8.6 docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html), and there is no mentioning of `each_with_index` there.
But if I start up Ruby 1.8.7 or 1.9.2 and run the following, it works:

```
h = {:a => 1, :b => 2.2}
h.each_with_index do |pair, i|
  p pair, i
end
```

Where does `each_with_index` come from? `Hash.superclasss` is `Object`, and `Object` doesn't implement this instance method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It comes from Enumerable, a module that's mixed in into Hash.

Do `Hash.ancestors` to find mention of Enumerable.

```
Hash.ancestors => [Hash, Enumerable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
Enumerable.instance_methods.grep(/each/) # => [:each_with_index, :reverse_each, :each_slice, :each_cons, :each_with_object]
```

Answer (score 2):

It comes from the `Enumerable` module, see [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html). The concept behind this is called `mixins` which is explained in detail [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html) and [here](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/06/15/mixins-in-ruby/).

Answer (score 1):

[Module enumerable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_m_enumerable.html)

Comment: Could you provide a little more explanation with your answer?